# Constructing Tri-Diagonal Matrices

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

Fractional Calculus Course, we are instructed to create an $n \times n$ Tri-Diagonal matrix in the form of:

\begin{array}
 a A &= \begin{bmatrix}
           2 & -1 & 0 & 0 &  ... & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0&... & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0& 0... & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  &-1 & 2 & -1 & ... & 0 & 0\\
&&&\vdots&&& \\
0 & 0 & 0&... & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&... & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
         \end{bmatrix} 
\end{array}

This is where my dilemma begins. I am not sure how to create this Tri-Diagonal Matrix. I came across the "SparseArray" command upon my research and it help me create a Tri-Diagonal Matrix, but I am having a hard time manipulating it to get the $-1, 2, -1$ pattern I am looking for.

```
mat = SparseArray[ {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] <= 1 :> 1, {10, 10}];
mat // MatrixForm
```

Above is the command I used for a $10 \times 10$ matrix. But the tri-diagonal entries were all 1's.

Thus my question is, how would I create the tri-diagonal matrix $n \times n$ I desire? Is there a way to create a function so I can simply manipulate the value of $n$ to get a new matrix without typing (or copy-pasting) the entire code again?

Comment: Look up `Band` in the help files.

Comment: Just curious ...What is a `Fractional Calculus Course` ?

Comment: Fractional Calculus is a course that focuses on the applications of fraction derivatives and fraction integrals. So imagine taking half the derivative of f(x) or the two-third integral of f(x). I'm still new to the material so I can't give you a better example that this, sorry.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(13004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13004/121).  Related: [(13796)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13796/121)

Answer (score 10):

```
SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 2, {i_, j_} :> -1 /; Abs[i - j] == 1}, {10, 10}]  // MatrixForm
```

or

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 2, Band[{2, 1}] -> -1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {10, 10}] //
                                                                             MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following is sometimes useful:

```
m = {{{a, b}, {b, a}}};
d = {10, 10};
SparseArray[{Band[{2, 2}, d] -> m, Band[{1, 1}, d] -> m}, d] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

Without `SparseArray`:

```
n = 10;
Total[
 {DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], -1], 
  DiagonalMatrix[Array[2 &, n]], 
  DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], 1]}
 ]
```

Or strictly using `Array`:

```
Array[Which[#1 == #2, 2, Abs[#1 - #2] == 1, -1, True, 0] &, {10, 10}]
```

AND, what the heck? One more for more flexible applications:

```
a = {2, -1, -2, 3};
n = 10;
With[{a1 = PadRight[a, n]}, (Array[a1[[Abs[#1 - #2] + 1]] &, {n, n}])]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Your second snippet is what was usually done before `SparseArray[]` came along.

Answer (score 7):

This should be faster (where *n* is your square dimension, e.g. 1000 for 1kX1k), easily extends to n-diagonal symmetric with no performance impact:

```
ToeplitzMatrix[PadRight[{2, -1}, n]]
```